# Why do Middleware implements no interface?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel < 5.2, middlewares implemented an interface described by this  contract: `Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware`.

Now, a Middleware created with artisan does not implement anything anymore. And [the contract was removed](https://github.com/illuminate/contracts/commit/02c53f7d5100a32901ed54cd7beaa46d3d06c6e3) with no explaination (unless I mistake).

Is there a reason?

Comment: it was mentioned in deprecation section of https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade but unfortunatly not able to get why it was deprecated

Comment: @ChetanAmeta You could post your comment as an anwser, and I will accept it!

Comment: added in the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per laravel 5.2 upgrade guide at [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/upgrade) under Deprecations section:

The `Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\Middleware` contract has been deprecated. No contract is required on your middleware. In addition, the `TerminableMiddleware` contract has also been deprecated. Instead of implementing the interface, simply define a `terminate` method on your middleware.

Answer (score 0):

I also noticed that middleware did not use an interface in other frameworks such as Slim and I read that Relay also does not use an interface.

The answer that [the Relay people gave](https://github.com/relayphp/Relay.Relay/issues/6) for their case was since a lot of middleware accepts closures (i.e. functions instead of classes) which generally can't be type hinted from php's perspective, forcing the use of an interface would not work. And if there isn't any forcing the implementation of an interface, then there is no point of using one.